# How do I mix conda environments for multi-projects in PyCharm?

Tags: python, conda, environment

I am currently facing a problem with mixed conda environments in PyCharm. Assuming I've a project A, which depends on project B and C. To keep things separated, project B and C each has their own conda file. Part of why project B and C are separated is because they have package dependencies that only works in specific versions of Python (3.8, 3.10). That said, I'd like to call functions from project B, B from project A. In that case how should I arrange my conda file for project A? I tried to use conda-merge but it gives me both python 3.8 and 3.10 in the exported env.yml which is clearly wrong. May I ask what's the typical procedure to deal with such problem?

I asked GPT and recommend me to use subprocess to activate the respective environment, looks quite hacky to me.

1. I tried conda-merge which gave me python 3.8, 3.10 in the export env.yml file
2. tried to use subprocess, but doesn't work in PyCharm, even though the cmd works in windows 11 CLI.

   ```
   result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True, env=env)
   ```